# Is ServletContext for 'localhost/prj' and 'xyz.com/prj' the same?

Tags: servlets, external, internal

According to the following code, internal and external access of a Tomcat project (prj.war), the ServletContext seems to be different. I state this because after a few internal access to the servlet, an external call resets the value and proceeds normally. May I have your opinions ? Thanks.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    response.setHeader("Connection",    "keep-alive");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
  //                                            P A R A M E T E R S                                              //
  //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    String x_value = request.getParameter("value"); if ( x_value == null ) {x_value = "0";}
  //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    String w_value = ( String ) getServletConfig().getServletContext().getAttribute("value");
    if   ( w_value == null ) {
           w_value = "0";
           getServletConfig().getServletContext().setAttribute("value", w_value);
           out.println("value reset !!!");
    }

    out.println("current value = " +   w_value);
    out.println("add     value = " +   x_value);
    out.println("total   value = " + ( w_value =    String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(w_value).intValue() + Integer.valueOf(x_value).intValue()) ));
    getServletConfig().getServletContext().setAttribute("value", w_value);
    out.println("new value set");
}
```

**EDIT :**

### SERVER.XML

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
</Host>

<!-- ************************ -->
<!-- package.xyz.com          -->
<!-- ************************ -->
  <Host name="package.xyz.com"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

    <Context docBase="package" path=""/>
  </Host>



<!-- ************************ -->
<!-- www.package.xyz.com      -->
<!-- ************************ -->
  <Host name="www.package.xyz.com"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

        <Context docBase="package" path=""/>
  </Host>
```

### INIT

```
@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Context is the same, no matter which way you are reaching it (internally or externally).  As stated in Oracle document:

> There is one context per "web application" per Java Virtual Machine. (A "web application" is a collection of servlets and content installed under a specific subset of the server's URL namespace such as /catalog and possibly installed via a .war file.)

Are you sure that your application is not reloaded (like hot deployment on the server)?

Comment: thanks for the response. i have no idea how your saying can be true as the entire code is above. i edited my question in order to include SERVER.XML and INIT method of the sample servlet.

Comment: i think, there is something tricky here : "...installed under a specific subset of the SERVER'S URL..." Accesing locally  / externally will change the URL naturally. Even xyz.com/prj and www.xyz.com/prj will have different servlet context.